# tar | pigz dies if run under cron

Tags: cron, compression, tar

I run a kind of backup script using tar joint with pigz for compression.

The problem is that

```
tar -zcf /file.tar.gz /folder
```

runs under cron.

While

```
tar -I pigz -cvf /file.tar.gz /folder
```

nor

```
tar cvf - /folder  | pigz > /file.tar.gz
```

do not...

It looks like it starts then die after few files.

How can I use pigz under cron ?

System is CentOs 5.x

Comment: did you try to use  "tar cv - /path  | pigz > /path/file.tar.gz" dont forgot to use semicolon 
do not...

Comment: I use absolute paths for all files and folders. Edited the question to reflect it.

Comment: while using cronetab you should use > " < on the start and end as the pipe might break if not been used

Comment: Sorry can't get the point. Can you give the example?

Comment: i already wrote in the first comment the exact command